# Get and set items in a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two classes: Group and Item.

```
public class Group
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
    }
```

And then Item

```
public class Item
    {
        public int ID{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public Group ItemGroup{ get; set; }

    }
```

Each group show have a set of items.

The following code is meant to get the list of items of a particular group.

```
 public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemByGroup(string group)
        {
             return repository.GetAllItems().Where
                (p =>p.ItemGroup.Name.Equals(group));
        }
```

Full controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

using TestService.Models;
using System.IO;

namespace TestService.Controllers
{
    public class ItemsController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IItemRepository repository = new ItemRepository();

        public IEnumerable<Item> GetAllItems()
        {
            return repository.GetAllItems();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemsByGroup(string group)
        {

            return repository.GetAllItems().Where
                (p => p.Category.Name.Equals(group));
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this I get the error: `No type was found that matches the controller named 'item'.` When I called it using `localhost:1234/api/item?group=group1`.

How do I get the list of items in a particular category specified by a string?

Comment: your url doesn't contain a controller name

Comment: The controller is item

Comment: this is an asp.net mvc apicontroller?

Comment: yes this is a mvc4 web api

Comment: Post the code for your controller.  (Hint: the route handler is looking for a class which derives from `ApiController` called `ItemController`.)

Comment: Post your code for the client as well.

Comment: See the code added in the question. I am using powershell ise to call.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is incorrect. Try .../api/**items** ... instead of .../api/**item**...

Comment: No that doesn't work. `localhost:1234/api/items` gets me the full list of items. The GetAllItems works, the GetItemsByGroup doesn't.

Comment: @Tester No, if you call `/api/items?group=someGroupName` it will invoke the proper function.

Comment: Yeah, you see Tester your controller is called Item **s** Controller, NOT ItemController. You can either rename your controller or simply change the URL to make the request work =]

Comment: ItemsController makes more sense since it uses the route `/api/items` to get all items and `/api/items/5` to get the item with an ID of 5.  Singular wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I agree with you Trevor. I was just emphasizing why the request wasn't working =]